# Rails 4: How to uninstall "actionpack-page_caching" and clear cache in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, caching, heroku, page-caching, action-caching

I tried using the 'actionpack-page_caching' gem to serve up static html pages on Heroku and discovered Heroku doesn't support it or at least makes it a little more difficult. The gem was working just fine in development but not in production and now the pages that I was trying to cache look all funky. While this not really a necessity in the first place, I'd like to just uninstall the gem but it looks like the server is still pushing out the cached version of the page.

I've tried uninstalling the gem ("gem uninstall actionpack-page_caching") and then clearing the cache (heroku run rails console Rails.cache.clear & heroku rake tmp:clear) and it has not worked. My files have been reverted back to how they looked originally so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

So I didn't realize that page_caching gem automatically created files in the app/public directory. I had to go in and delete those and then I cleared the browser history and cookies. All seems to be working fine now in both dev and prod.